# Print error when the variables name changed in another script

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-requests

## MY QUESTION:

Once I change the variables name from: `num = []` to `nbr = []` only in `privicy.py` I'm getting

> `NameError: name 'numbers' is not defined`

instead of this, I need to print my message here as `"YOU CHANGED THE STRUCTURE"`

## Folder structure:

> -Main Folder
>
> ------main.py
>
> -Details Folder
>
> ------details.py
>
> ------Privacy Folder
>
> -----------privicy.py

## main.py

```
for n in numbers :
    if n not in numbers :
        sys.exit()

sms_count = int(input("ENTER SMS COUNTS : "))
```

## details.py

```
numbers = [777777,777778,7777710]
```

## privicy.py

```
num = [777777,777778,7777710]
```

## Note:

When I run **main.py** it will check if the **details.py** `numbers = [777777,777778,7777710]` are in **privicy.py** `num = [777777,777778,7777710]`.

Comment: `num` (and `number `) aren't class names, they are just a variables — so your question makes little sense. I also suggest you learn how to format your questions here better, see [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: i have changed class to variable thank you for your guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am writing this answer by assuming that you are importing the files that you need to access the variables from.

> Once I change the variables name from: num = [] to nbr = [] only in privicy.py
> I'm getting
> `NameError: name 'numbers' is not defined`
> instead of this, I need to print my message here as "YOU CHANGED THE STRUCTURE"

For this you can use something like:

```
try:
    ...
except NameError:
    print("YOU CHANGED THE STRUCTURE")
```

And in your main.py file, you are using `if` condition running loop over `numbers` list and checking if the number in `numbers` list exist in the same list i.e `numbers`. Perhaps you might have wanted to do something like:

```
for n in numbers :
    if n not in num :
        sys.exit()
```